# manually added products not showing on site?

Tags: product

I have manually added simple products to a grouped product but nothing showing on website?!  Checked they are enabled AND showing stock AND not duplicated but still not showing ?

Comment: Run bin/magento indexer:reidex && bin/magento c:f